# How to implement logger in angular 2 application and send client side logs to server side

Tags: angular, logging, server

I am new in angular 2 application. Developing web application using angular2. I want to add logger in my application.

Kindly suggest best way to implement logger and send logs to server.

Comment: I can suggest you to extend/inherit from built-in `Error` class and do the job in this descendant class. It will also allow you to handle errors properly. Or you can utilize [@nsalaun/ng2-logger](https://github.com/noemi-salaun/ng-logger) or [angular2-logger](https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger)

Comment: I have intergrated loger into my angular 2 application using angular2-logger. but i dont know How can i send that logs to server. I need to maintain user navigation logs.

Answer (score 0):

If someone bumps into this now, I just saw this great project here : Lumberjack for Angular :
https://youtu.be/OV1ONtLAJnI

It looks good so far and has built in Drivers for external services.

https://github.com/ngworker/lumberjack/